# Laravel: test.sqlite does not exist on every first run

Tags: linux, laravel, testing, phpunit, phpstorm

I get this error if I start a test:

> Database file at path [database/test.sqlite] does not exist

If I run the same test again, works. I can run it over and over again and it keeps working.
Sometimes when I run a different test the error comes again for one time. I can not reproduce when it comes again.

From `phpunit.xml`

```
<php>
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>

    <server name="APP_URL" value="http://localhost"/>

    <env name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
    <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
    <env name="DB_DATABASE" value="database/test.sqlite"/>
    <env name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
    <env name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
    <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
</php>
```

From `config/database.php`:

```
    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => '',
        'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
    ],
```

Maybe someone knows why or how to debug this?

Comment: Do you run any test and fails, and then you run it again and works? next time, will it fail again or always work? what connection do you have set? You should have `DB_CONNECTION=sqlite` and `DB_DATABASE=:memory:` (unless you want to really use an existing database for `sqlite` but you would need that file)

Comment: @matiaslauriti I added my phpunit settings. It does always work. But I do get the error again sometimes. I think when I switch to a different test, but not always.

Comment: DB_DATABASE is defined twice in your phpunit.xml. Has 'sqlite' connection in your config/database.php the default values?

Comment: @PiTheNumber you have double `DB_DATABASE`... which one do you want? `in-memory` => `:memory:`...

Comment: @John: Thanks, I removed the duplicate and added `config/databasephp`. Should be default.

Comment: @PiTheNumber If it's still happening try checking at tests/CreatesApplication.php whether database file exists and environment values are the expected ones or not in order to determine if something is deleting your database or is a config issue. I hope this helps.

Comment: @John Thanks, I checked if test.sqlite exists in CreatesApplication first line, after bootstrap and in the test again. They all saying the file it there (which it is), but still I get "Database file at path [database/test.sqlite] does not exist".

Comment: @PiTheNumber I'm out of ideas then. Or there's another test.sqlite file which phpunit is searching for, don't know how or where, which is created after the first test run or I don't know what else to look for, sorry.